# Combine dictionaries with the same value for a specific key

Tags: python

I have a group of dictionaries of 2 patterns like `{"Id": 1, "title":"example"}` and `{"Id": 1, "location":"city"}`. I want to combine these 2 together to get `{"Id": 1, "title":"example", "location":"city"}`, for all the dictionaries with `Id`s that match. In this case the group is of 200 items of 100 `title`s and 100 `location`s all with `Id`s from 0-99. I want to return a list of 100 combined dictionaries.

May be like the following:

```py
def ResultHandler(extractedResult: list):
    jsonObj = {}
    jsonList = []
    for result in extractedResult:
        for key, val in result.items():
            #this works if its hardcoded val to a number...
            if key == "Id" and val == 1:
                jsonObj.update(result)
    jsonList.append(jsonObj)
    return jsonList
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Group the dicts by ID. Then merge each group.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def merge_dicts(dicts):
    grouped = defaultdict(list)
    for d in dicts:
        grouped[d['id']].append(d)

    merged = []
    for ds in grouped.values():
        m = {}
        for d in ds:
            m |= d        # If Python < 3.9 : m = {**m, **d}
        merged.append(m)

    return merged
```

Comment: No need for an inner `for` loop with <3.9, use the ** unpacker: `m = {**m, **d}`

Comment: This worked great, I would definitely like to get rid of that inner for loop if possible but don't understand what you mean by using the unpacker.

Comment: @Spencer There is no inner loop to be gotten rid of. If you have Python 3.9 or higher, use `m |= d`; otherwise, use the syntax in the code comment.

Comment: The inner `for` loop was in reference to something FMc said in their original answer. It's no longer relevant.

Comment: Got it! also in that explanation the "for k, ds in grouped.items():", k is never used. Can you just do "for val in grouped.values():"?

Comment: @AlphabetSoup Yes, that is better. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

A more functional (but slightly less efficient) approach:

```py
from itertools import groupby
from functools import reduce
from operator import itemgetter


new_data = []
for _, g in groupby(sorted(data, key=itemgetter("Id")), key=itemgetter("Id")):
    new_data.append(reduce(lambda d1, d2: {**d1, **d2}, g))
```

Answer (score 0):

This function has a nested loop. The outer loop iterates through the list of dictionaries. The inner loop
iterates through the list of dictionaries again to check if the id of the current dictionary is
already in the list of dictionaries. If it is not, it appends the dictionary to the list of
dictionaries. If it is, it updates the dictionary in the list of dictionaries with the contents of
the current dictionary.

```
lst = [
    {"id": 1, "fname": "John"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Bob"},
    {"id": 1, "lname": "Mary"},
]
def combine_dicts(lst):
    res = []
    for d in lst:
        if d.get("id") not in [x.get("id") for x in res]:
            res.append(d)
        else:
            for r in res:
                if r.get("id") == d.get("id"):
                    r.update(d)
    return res


print(combine_dicts(last))
# output: [{'id': 1, 'fname': 'John', 'lname': 'Mary'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'Bob'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work:

```
def resultHandler(extractedResult):
  jsonList = []
  for i in range(len(extractedResult) // 2):
    jsonList.append({"Id": i})
  for i in range(len(extractedResult)):
    for j in range(len(jsonList)):
      if jsonList[j]["Id"] == extractedResult[i]["Id"]:
        if "title" in extractedResult[i]:
          jsonList[j]["title"] = extractedResult[i]["title"];
        else:
          jsonList[j]["location"] = extractedResult[i]["location"];
  return jsonList;

extractedResult = [{"Id": 0, "title":"example1"}, {"Id": 1, "title":"example2"}, {"Id": 0, "location":"example3"}, {"Id": 1, "location":"example4"}]

jsonList = resultHandler(extractedResult)

print(jsonList)
```

Output:

```
[{'Id': 0, 'title': 'example1', 'location': 'example3'}, {'Id': 1, 'title': 'example2', 'location': 'example4'}]
```

This code works by first filling up `jsonList` with Id values from 0 to half of the length of `extractedResult` (so the number of IDs).

Then, for every dictionary in `extractedResult`, we find the dictionary in `jsonList` with the matching ID. If that dictionary of `extractedResult` contains a key, `"title"`, then we create that value for that dictionary in `jsonList`. The same applied for `"location"`.

I hope this helps answer your question! Please let me know if you need any further clarification or details :)

Answer (score 0):

This code will solve your problem in linear time i.e., O(n) where n is the order of growth of the length of your dictionary. It will consider only those `Id` which has both `title` and `location` and will ignore the rest.

```
from collections import Counter

data = [{"Id": 1, "title":"example1"},
        {"Id": 2, "title":"example2"},
        {"Id": 3, "title":"example3"},
        {"Id": 4, "title":"example4"},
        {"Id": 1, "location":"city1"},
        {"Id": 2, "location":"city2"},
        {"Id": 4, "location":"city4"},
        {"Id": 5, "location":"city5"}]

paired_ids = set([key for key, val in dict(Counter([item["Id"] for item in data])).items() if val == 2]) # O(n)

def combine_dict(data):
    result = {key: [] for key in paired_ids} # O(m), m: number of paired ids (m <= n/2)
    for item in data: # O(n)
        items = list(item.items())
        id, tl, val = items[0][1], items[1][0], items[1][1]

        if id in paired_ids: # O(1), as paired_ids is a set lookup takes O(1)
            result[id].append({tl: val})

    return [{"Id": id, "title": lst[0]["title"], "location": lst[1]["location"]} for id, lst in result.items()] # O(n)


print(*combine_dict(data), sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
{'Id': 1, 'title': 'example1', 'location': 'city1'}
{'Id': 2, 'title': 'example2', 'location': 'city2'}
{'Id': 4, 'title': 'example4', 'location': 'city4'}
```